# Add Indicator on top of TabBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Like this one:

[image]

Below code will add Indicator bottom of TabBar:

```
  DefaultTabController(
    length: 2,
    child : new TabBar(
      labelColor: Colors.purple,
      indicatorColor: Colors.purple,
      indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
    tabs: [
        new Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.chrome_reader_mode),),
        new Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.clear_all),),
    ]),
  );
```

But I need `Indicator` on top of `TabBar`. I don't think it's a great idea to build a custom tab bar because, I don't want to do lot of works for this simple thing.

Comment: This might be very late- but you can check out this article https://medium.com/swlh/flutter-custom-tab-indicator-for-tabbar-d72bbc6c9d0c

Answer (score 26):

There is a simple hack and that is to use [`indicator`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TabBar/indicator.html) property and add `UnderlineTabIndicator()` and that class has named parameter called `insets` and as the value I added `EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50.0, 0.0, 50.0, 40.0),`

> Left: 50.0, // make indicator small by 50.0 from left
>
> Top:  0.0,
>
> Right:  50.0, // make indicator small by 50.0 from right
>
> Bottom:  40.0 // pushed indicator to top by 40.0 from bottom

like below:

```
const textStyle = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 12.0,
    color: Colors.white,
    fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600);

//.....
new TabBar(
  controller: controller,
  labelColor: Color(0xFF343434),
  labelStyle: textStyle.copyWith(
      fontSize: 20.0,
      color: Color(0xFFc9c9c9),
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
  indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xDD613896), width: 8.0),
    insets: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50.0, 0.0, 50.0, 40.0),
  ),
  unselectedLabelColor: Color(0xFFc9c9c9),
  unselectedLabelStyle: textStyle.copyWith(
      fontSize: 20.0,
      color: Color(0xFFc9c9c9),
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
  tabs: [
    new Tab(
      text: 'LOGIN',
    ),
    new Tab(
      text: 'SIGNUP',
    ),
  ],
),
```

Also you can create a custom indicator extending [`Decoration`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/Decoration-class.html)

Answer (score 13):

Another option is to define a new `Decoration` for the `indicator:` property of the `TabBar` widget, in this way you're not bound to the TabBar height (as with using `insets: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50.0, 0.0, 50.0, 40.0),`), but you can't create an indicator smaller than the tab itself.

here the code:

```dart
TabBar(
  indicator: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border(
      top: BorderSide(
        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        width: 3.0
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Yeah, both way we have limitations. But your solution is greater for responsiveness of devices.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom ***TabController*** for this. I found a simple example of Flutter TabBar [Here](https://www.developerlibs.com/2018/06/flutter-tab-bar-controller-and-left.html). You can check it in detail here.

Comment: What you're saying is not relevant to this question. I mean a line(indicator) above tab(default is under each tab)

Comment: No, the line only visible for selected tab.

Comment: No, thats for the drawer and I dont see any changes to tabbar indicator its in bottom not on top. Look at the image above. and while there is a simple hack as expressed by the other answer, why I make my class complicate. Any reasons?